# Laurent series $\frac{-1}{z}+\frac{1}{2(z-1)} +\frac{1}{2(z+1)}$ at |z-1| > 2

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

This is what I tried to do.
Is this correct?
[image]

Comment: `I assume we only consider the third fraction?` Wrong assumption. Can you find the laurent series on the annulus $\{z\in \mathbb C\colon |z-1|>1\}$ of each fraction?

Comment: @GitGud Sorry, I don't really know how to do this

Comment: @anon For instance $$\dfrac{1}{z}=\dfrac{1}{1+(z-1)}=\dfrac{1}{z-1}\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{-1}{z-1}}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left((-1)^n\left(\dfrac{1}{z-1}\right)^{n+1}\right),$$ if $\left|\dfrac{1}{z-1}\right|<1$ or equivalently $|z-1|>1$. It will probably be the case that the last fraction will only work for $|z-1|>2$ so the laurent series asked will work on $|z-1|>1\land |z-1|>2$ which is equivalent to $|z-1|>$2.

Comment: @GitGud Why is it necessary to divide by the z-1 in the second inequality? Why can we not just have a taylor series with an alternating (z-1)^n term?

Comment: Because then you'll get the series on the annulus $|z-1|<1$ which isn't what you want.

Comment: @gitgud So I have written the third term as $\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-1}{3+z}}$. Is this right or should it be  $\frac{1}{1+\frac{3+z}{z-1}}$ ? Edit: Sorry I meant both of these multiplied by $\frac{1}{z-1}$

Comment: @GitGud Sorry I don't really understand why. Could you explain please?

Comment: @anon When is the formula $\dfrac{1}{1-r}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(r^n\right)$ valid?

Comment: @GitGud for |r| < 1?

Comment: Okay, I follow now

Comment: @GitGud so is what I posted for the third term right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24055/discussion-between-anon-and-git-gud).

Comment: @anon I'm not around the computer at the moment. Can't join the chat. I don't know if what you wrote is correct or not. But it isn't going in the right direction anyway. You need to write it in terms of $z-1$, try writing the denominator as $2(3+(z-1))$.

Comment: @GitGud I have uploaded a picture to the original question of what I meant, thanks!

Comment: I didn't check every little thing, but you got the right idea.

Comment: @gitgud Great- thank you! Hopefully I will pass my exam on Thursday! Haha

Comment: Good luck.${{}}$